# Organizar data recebida e alterar, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Eu recebo duas divs do servidor dessa forma:

```
 <div id="1"></div>
 <div id="2"></div>
```

Porem essas divs ja existem na pagina, entao eu queria apenas atualizar seus devidos conteudos, eu recebo elas de uma requisição AJAX, como faze-las?

Comment: Podes explicar melhor? então recebes esse HTML do servidor mas já existem divs com essa ID e queres substituir o HTML nas que já existem pelas que vêm do servidor?

Comment: @Sergio isso mesmo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que podes fazer é procurar dentro dessa resposta do servidor os elementos e iterar  para retirar a ID. Acho que vai funcionar apesar de ID terem de ser únicas.

Porém o melhor mesmo era o servidor retornar um JSON com o por exemplo:

```
`{ "umaID": "html", "outraID": "html, etc...`
```

Mas usando o que tens e o que está na pergunta, testa assim:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"teste.php",  
    success:function(data) {
        $(data).find('*').each(function(){
            $('#' + this.id).html(this.innerHTML);
        }); 
    }
});
```